# Azure Monitoring Agent MDSD is not able to open tcp socket to connect to different machine

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring

We are using the following command to start the mdsd process:

```
start("mdsd", "-a", "-C", "-j", "-T", "0x100000", "0x200000", "0x40000", "0x4000", "0x2002", "-c", "/etc/mdsd.d/mdsd.xml", "-r", MDSD_ROLE_PREFIX, "-e", MDSD_LOG+"/mdsd.err", "-w", MDSD_LOG+"/mdsd.warn", "-o", MDSD_LOG+"/mdsd.info", "-q", MDSD_LOG+"/mdsd.qos", "-L", MDSD_EVENTS_PERSIST_PATH, "-p", MDSD_PORT)
```

Even though we are specifying -p option we can see it's not via tcp_json but only json:
2024-01-30T14:30:12.6149880Z:

virtual void Subscription::execute(const MdsTime&) (.../mdsd/Subscription.cc +83) Start time 2024-01-30T14:25:00.0000000Z, end time 2024-01-30T14:30:00.0000000Z
2024-01-30T14:30:12.6200070Z: virtual void Subscription::execute(const MdsTime&) (.../mdsd/Subscription.cc +119) Processed 0 lines for 0x2de06c0 (Event [Bond]azurenfsaasfileaccesslogsver1v0, interval 300)
**2024-01-30T14:30:15.4814710Z: void ProtocolListener::run() (.../mdsd/ProtocolListener.cc +168) New connection is ready for protocol 'json' on fd=22**

I am able to start the process but when creating the client on a different host than where the process is running, I am not able to receive the ack from mdsd and it gets stuck on Read:

```
conn, err = net.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:9001")

chunk := make([]byte, 10)
read, err := conn.Read(chunk)
if err != nil {
    //return received, buffer.Bytes(), err
}
```

**So how do we make mdsd listen to AF_INET tcp socket instead of AF_UNIX when starting mdsd process(what arguments to pass)?**

```
root@20034a5fbc49:/var/run/mdsd# ls
default.lock  default.pidport  default_bond.socket  default_djson.socket  default_fluent.socket  default_influx.socket  default_json.socket  default_syslog.socket
```

Answer (score 0):

> **So how do we make mdsd listen to AF_INET tcp socket instead of AF_UNIX when starting mdsd process(what arguments to pass)?**

MDSD is correctly configured to listen on an `AF_INET` TCP socket.

- To make mdsd listen on TCP sockets, we need to specify the TCP transport protocol when starting the mdsd process. Usually, mdsd provides options to specify the protocol and the address to bind to.

**Start cmd:**

```bash
start("mdsd", "-a", "-C", "-j", "-T", "0x100000", "0x200000", "0x40000", "0x4000", "0x2002", "-c", "/etc/mdsd.d/mdsd.xml", "-r", MDSD_ROLE_PREFIX, "-e", MDSD_LOG+"/mdsd.err", "-w", MDSD_LOG+"/mdsd.warn", "-o", MDSD_LOG+"/mdsd.info", "-q", MDSD_LOG+"/mdsd.qos", "-L", MDSD_EVENTS_PERSIST_PATH, "-p", "tcp://127.0.0.1:9001")
```

TCP transport is `-t`, and I want mdsd to listen on TCP port 9001,

- I see that you are not specifying a parameter for the transport protocol. In many cases, mdsd has separate parameters for specifying the transport protocol and the address to bind to.

[image]